# Spatialite ST_area(geom) won't compute for GeomObject

Tags: qgis, wikimapia, qspatialite

I extracted a dataset from Wikimapia via API using .kml download --> ogr2ogr .kml to GML -explodecollections --> GML to .shp only LINESTRING part of geometry collection.

Running QSpatiatlie in QGIS, I'm trying to run

SELECT name, ST_Area(geom)

but I'm getting only zeroes under the ST_Area(geom) column. No SQL errors.

Is this a geometry issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand your question but since lines have no area, it would seem like zero is the expected result.

Comment: However, you can convert linestring into polygon first:
`select ST_Area(ST_BuildArea(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0,1 1,0 1,0 0)')))` If linestring is not closed you must make it closed before using ST_BuildArea.

Comment: My thoughts as well. But they're closed linestrings, at least I think so. The way they are digitized in Wikimapia is no different than on Google Earth or QGIS. I'm hoping for another ogr2ogr or processing waythrough.

Comment: If they are closed linestrings then linestring->buildarea>area chain will work. Modify your query into `SELECT name, ST_Area(ST_BuildArea(geom)) AS area FROM...` and try.